# how to use multiple modofier to form combinations of boolean conditions?

Tags: solidity, modifiers

I have read [this](https://ethereumdev.io/better-readability-with-modifiers/) article and this [SO](https://ethereumdev.io/better-readability-with-modifiers/). And I understand the functionality of modifier. When modifiers are placed on a function with a spacing they will be evaluated in the order of placing thus creating an **And** condition. However, I would to understand how multiple modifiers can be placed so that combination of other Boolean conditions such as **OR** be evaluated?

For Instance,

```
modifier modA {
  // verify something
  _;
  // verify something
  _;
}
modifier modB {
  // verify something
  _;
  // verify something
  _;
}
function Fun() modA modB {
  // Do something
}
```

In this case, *modA AND modB* will be the execution. But is it possible to use them to form OR condition?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way in solidity. I'll explain you why. Modifier is like a macro function while compiling it will replace your modifier with its actuval implementation. Here _; replace with your function implementation.

```
contract ModiferTesting {
   uint public a;
   uint public b;
   uint public c;

   modifier modA() {
    a = a + 1;
    _;
   }

   modifier modB() {
    b = b + 1;
    _;
    b = b + 1;
    _;
    b = b + 1;
    _;
  }

  function test() public modA modB {
    c = c + 1;
  }
}
```

If you debug, above code you can find a=1, b=3, c=3

Try to write an other modifier that check's or condition.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I understand the part that you explained. but isn't the original idea behind modifiers is to evaluate the preconditions? so if `modA` and `modB` only checks certain conditions, shouldn't be somehow possible to obtain other boolean results? Also how `c=3`? it should be 4, right?